# build for my react-native app fails after I install tipsi-stripe

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm building an Android app in react-native and I need to add a payment page with Stripe. 
Unfortunately after I run `yarn add tipsi-stripe` and `react-native link tipsi-stripe` builds are failing with an exception for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
I would be grateful for any advice because I need to finish this by Wednesday.

I tried `gradlew clean` and installing other versions of `tipsy-stripe`

my respository: https://github.com/proud-stories/proud-stories

Log with error: android/build.gradle

Environment:
tipsi-stripe version: 7.5.0
OS version: Android 9.0
React-Native version: 0.59.9

Comment: Looking at your build.gradle you haven’t added multidex support, you may require adding this. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: It also looks like you are using both yarn and npm for installing dependencies. You should pick one and use it exclusively.

Comment: @Andrew 
Thanks for the hint! I'll try adding multidex. Hope it'll fix it

I know about npm + yarn... I use yarn but one of my teammates cannot stop installing npm :/

Comment: I added multidex but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I could fix this problem by adding these lines to android/app/build.gradle:

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile (project(':tipsi-stripe')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
        }
}
and also adding multiDexEnabled true to defaultConfig

Comment: @viktor awesome! glad to hear it :D

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this problem by adding these lines to android/app/build.gradle: implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0' compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' compile (project(':tipsi-stripe')) { exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms' exclude group: 'com.google.firebase' } } and also adding multiDexEnabled true to defaultConfig